# Redux update nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I can't figure out how to update an array inside my object using a Redux reducer.
I have been searching for quite a while, looked at the Redux docs, and the code I wrote looks like the ones I saw there, but it just doesn't work properly for some reason.

My state before the update looks like this:

```js
{
  groups: {
    groups: [
      {
        _id: '5f7f5a3097d3b6a8e49086a5',
        name: 'asd3',
        avatar_color: '#ffffff',
        avatar_bgcolor: '#000000'
      },
      {
        _id: '5f7f5a4397d3b6a8e49086a6',
        name: 'asd fgh',
        avatar_color: '#000000',
        avatar_bgcolor: '#ffffff'
      }
    ],
    currentGroup: {
      _id: '5f7f5a3097d3b6a8e49086a5',
      messageCount: 10,
      messages: [
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b262657b148406cad5',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 0',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:58:58.181Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:58:58.181Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b462657b148406cad6',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 1',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:00.902Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:00.902Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b662657b148406cad7',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 2',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:02.731Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:02.731Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b862657b148406cad8',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 3',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:04.360Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:04.360Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99ba62657b148406cad9',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 4',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:06.052Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:06.052Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99bb62657b148406cada',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 5',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:07.870Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:07.870Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7fa6090c7e871c1f1d400d',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 6',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T23:51:37.772Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T23:51:37.772Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7fabf00c7e871c1f1d400f',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 7',
          createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:16:48.795Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:16:48.795Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7faee20c7e871c1f1d4010',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 8',
          createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:29:22.360Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:29:22.360Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7faf8f0c7e871c1f1d4011',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 9',
          createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:32:15.747Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:32:15.747Z'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add a message to the messages array inside the currentGroup object.

I tried the following code for my reducer:

```js
case ADD_CHAT_MESSAGE:
    return {
        ...state,
        currentGroup: {
            ...state.currentGroup,
            messages: [...state.currentGroup.messages, action.payload]
        }
    };
```

When I run this, the contents of currentGroup get spread inside the messages object (along with the old messages array), then the new message gets added into that inner object's messages array like so:

```js
{
  groups: {
    groups: [
      {
        _id: '5f7f5a3097d3b6a8e49086a5',
        name: 'asd3',
        avatar_color: '#ffffff',
        avatar_bgcolor: '#000000'
      },
      {
        _id: '5f7f5a4397d3b6a8e49086a6',
        name: 'asd fgh',
        avatar_color: '#000000',
        avatar_bgcolor: '#ffffff'
      }
    ],
    currentGroup: {
      _id: '5f7f5a3097d3b6a8e49086a5',
      messageCount: 10,
      messages: [
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b262657b148406cad5',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 0',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:58:58.181Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:58:58.181Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b462657b148406cad6',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 1',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:00.902Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:00.902Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b662657b148406cad7',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 2',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:02.731Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:02.731Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99b862657b148406cad8',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 3',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:04.360Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:04.360Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99ba62657b148406cad9',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 4',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:06.052Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:06.052Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7f99bb62657b148406cada',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 5',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:07.870Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:07.870Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7fa6090c7e871c1f1d400d',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 6',
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T23:51:37.772Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-08T23:51:37.772Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7fabf00c7e871c1f1d400f',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 7',
          createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:16:48.795Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:16:48.795Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7faee20c7e871c1f1d4010',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 8',
          createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:29:22.360Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:29:22.360Z'
        },
        {
          _id: '5f7faf8f0c7e871c1f1d4011',
          sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
          type: 'text',
          message: 'test message 9',
          createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:32:15.747Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:32:15.747Z'
        },
        {
          members: [
            '5f699fffc51562181fe52879'
          ],
          _id: '5f7f5a3097d3b6a8e49086a5',
          name: 'asd3',
          avatar_color: '#ffffff',
          avatar_bgcolor: '#000000',
          messages: [
            {
              _id: '5f7f99b262657b148406cad5',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 0',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:58:58.181Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:58:58.181Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7f99b462657b148406cad6',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 1',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:00.902Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:00.902Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7f99b662657b148406cad7',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 2',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:02.731Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:02.731Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7f99b862657b148406cad8',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 3',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:04.360Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:04.360Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7f99ba62657b148406cad9',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 4',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:06.052Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:06.052Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7f99bb62657b148406cada',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 5',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:07.870Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T22:59:07.870Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7fa6090c7e871c1f1d400d',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 6',
              createdAt: '2020-10-08T23:51:37.772Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-08T23:51:37.772Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7fabf00c7e871c1f1d400f',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 7',
              createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:16:48.795Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:16:48.795Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7faee20c7e871c1f1d4010',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 8',
              createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:29:22.360Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:29:22.360Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7faf8f0c7e871c1f1d4011',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 9',
              createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:32:15.747Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:32:15.747Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7fb03a0c7e871c1f1d4012',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 10',
              createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:35:06.025Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:35:06.025Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7fb15c0c7e871c1f1d4014',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 10',
              createdAt: '2020-10-09T00:39:56.477Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-09T00:39:56.477Z'
            },
            {
              _id: '5f7fb76e0c7e871c1f1d401c',
              sender: '5f699fffc51562181fe52879',
              type: 'text',
              message: 'test message 10',
              createdAt: '2020-10-09T01:05:50.511Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-10-09T01:05:50.511Z'
            }
          ],
          createdAt: '2020-10-08T18:28:00.475Z',
          updatedAt: '2020-10-09T01:05:50.511Z',
          __v: 13
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any tips how to make this work?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Consider flattening your state instead of nesting. Look into ReduxORM..

Comment: I would recommend normalizing the data according to this guideline https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thanks for the reference, I decided to refactor this hell :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to refactor the state structure as advised by the comments. Thank you guys!
Based on the reference I got, I have to normalize the data so that I can then manipulate it easily without having to deal with nested objects.